# Decode qr codes with python from left to right

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, qr-code, zbar

I have a png with several qr codes which basically looks like this

[image]

To decode the qr codes I use `zbarlight`.

```
from PIL import Image
import zbarlight

file_path = './tests/qr_codes.png'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
    image = Image.open(image_file)
    image.load()

codes = zbarlight.scan_codes(['qrcode'], image)
print('QR codes: %s' % codes)
```

My goal is to decode the qr codes FROM LEFT TO RIGHT, so the list should like like this: url1, url2, url3, url4, url5, ulr6.

Problem: The result (list) of the zbarlight scanning process looks to me like a random order. Is there a way to scan FROM LEFT TO RIGHT?

Comment: Split the codes into separate images, and take them in the desired order.

Comment: @Prune: I thought about it. The problem is I have hundreds of files and sometimes I have 3, 4, 5 or 6 qr codes on one page. How can I automatically split/extract the qr codes in separate files?

Comment: You apply image processing techniques to find the features that define each individual code: vertical white bands, the three corners, or whatever works for you.

Comment: I just asked: [How to split qr codes in separate images?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51196028/7082264)

Comment: It might also help to post a full question here: include the order your want, and the order you got.  Unless we already have QR-code scanners, we can't decode these on our own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on windows, no way of testing on linux right now, but this appears to work as expected.

```
import sys, os
try:
    from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, ZBarSymbol
except:
    cmd = ('py -m pip install "pyzbar"')
    os.system(cmd)
    from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, ZBarSymbol

try:
    from PIL import Image
except:
    cmd = ('py -m pip install "Pillow"')
    os.system(cmd)
    from PIL import Image

decoded = decode(Image.open("C:/Temp/13AZQ.png"), symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])
qr_dic = {}
for qr in decoded:
    x = qr[2][0] # The Left position of the QR code
    qr_dic[x] = qr[0] # The Data stored in the QR code

for qr in sorted(qr_dic.keys()):
    print(qr_dic[qr])
```

Output:

```
b'url1'
b'url2'
b'url3'
b'url4'
b'url5'
```