# How to split qr codes in separate images?

Tags: python, linux, image, qr-code

I have hundreds of pictures with qr codes (sometimes there are 0, 1, 2 or more qr codes on one page...but they are always in one line). I want to [decode the qr codes from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51195584/7082264). My idea is to split the qr codes in separate images.

Does somebody know a Linux (or Python) solution for this problem?

[image]

The order I want is: url1, url2, url3, url4, url5, url6.

Comment: Are they all the same size ?

Comment: Looks like pyzbar has no trouble with multiple qr codes.

Comment: @Marco: Yes, they're.

Comment: @tgikal: zbarlight does the job too. The problem is the order.

Comment: pyzbar does also provide the position of the image in its output, a sort shouldn't be too much trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on windows, no way of testing on linux right now, but this appears to work as expected.

```
import sys, os
try:
    from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, ZBarSymbol
except:
    cmd = ('py -m pip install "pyzbar"')
    os.system(cmd)
    from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, ZBarSymbol

try:
    from PIL import Image
except:
    cmd = ('py -m pip install "Pillow"')
    os.system(cmd)
    from PIL import Image

decoded = decode(Image.open("C:/Temp/13AZQ.png"), symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])
qr_dic = {}
for qr in decoded:
    x = qr[2][0] # The Left position of the QR code
    qr_dic[x] = qr[0] # The Data stored in the QR code

for qr in sorted(qr_dic.keys()):
    print(qr_dic[qr])
```

Output:

```
b'url1'
b'url2'
b'url3'
b'url4'
b'url5'
```

Comment: storing the left position as a dictionary key, then returning the data through sorted keys seemed like the easiest method to me.

Comment: I just managed to get things done (with your help). Thanks you very much! If you post your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51195584/7082264) too, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on a pretty locked down computer and it would not let me install zbarlight to even let me see if I could get that one to work in the same way.